# Remove custom type in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

In Alfresco, if a type name is removed/changed all nodes of that type will disappears but still exists.

Using alfresco 5.0.c I've added some custom types:

eg:

```
<type name="my:test">
    <title>Test folder</title>
    <parent>cm:folder</parent>
</type>
```

now i deploy it and create a folder of this type (a simple folder, then change type)

Now i edit the type like this:

```
 <type name="my:test2"> <!-- from my:test to my:test2 -->
        <title>Test folder</title>
        <parent>cm:folder</parent>
    </type>
```

Deploying this: any "my:test" folder will disappear, but, if I try to create another folder with the same name I get an error becouse the node still exists.
These nodes will not be not even listed within the folder child:

```
print(document.getChildren());
```

How can I recover (if possible using the the [javascript console](https://github.com/share-extras/js-console)) all the "broken" nodes and be able to change the type?

Answer (score 4):

A little preface: as widely stated by Alfresco, if you want to change your custom content model you should change it only incrementally.
This means that you can't remove any properties, types or aspect at definition level of the model, you only can add new definitions in the content model of Alfresco.

So it is a very bad practice to change types "on the fly".
A good practice is to always start with a model as small as you can and then add features as long as you need them.

In your case you should have deleted all nodes referencing `my:test` type BEFORE changing the model and then safely remove it and finally you should have performed a full reindex. This could be the reason why the repository tells you that the folder exists even if you cannot see it anymore.

As far as I know it is not possible to delete this inconsistent nodes through the console, so my advice is to perform a full reindex. If the issues come up again then you should consider to start again from scratch.

Another approach next time is to add the new type and programmatically hide the older one.